# Order of Constructor,getters and setters in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have just started with `Hibernate` and wanted to know the order of how the `getters`, `setters` and `constructors` are called while persisting and reading to/from database. I ran a simple program and below is the order of call to getters,setters and constructor.

**Main**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory().openSession();


session.getTransaction().begin();


Teacher t = new Teacher("John");
session.save(t);
Teacher t1= (Teacher) session.get(Teacher.class,1);


session.getTransaction().commit();



session.close();
```

**Teacher**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @Column
    String name;



    public Teacher(String name) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
    }

    public Teacher()
    {
        System.out.println("const");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) 
    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("get Name");
        return name;
    }
    @Column
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) 
    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("set Name");
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**O/P**

```
get Name
Hibernate: insert into janumerijaan (name) values (?)
Hibernate: select teacher0_.id as id1_2_0_, teacher0_.name as name2_2_0_ from janumerijaan teacher0_ where teacher0_.id=?
const
set Name
get Name
get Name
```

Can someone please explain why there is a call to `getters` twice at the end of the output

Comment: I can say for sure your implementation should not be based on the order and number of calls getter/setter.

Comment: @SternK, my implementation is not based on them. I am just trying to understand how does the object get created after getting retrieved from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which hibernate version you are using, but I checked with hibernate 5.4.15.Final to figure out where and why those additional get methods are called.

During commit operation there are multiple places where get method of corresponding entity called. It is mainly for 3 reasons;

- Preparing for entity flushes (to check cascade relations)
- Flushing entities
- Logging flush results

[Here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/17152bfbba27c23c97cae763accf1430f0fce6ea/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.java#L72) you can see the method 'flushEverythingToExecutions' in class 'AbstractFlushingEventListener' that includes above 3 operations on which get method of entities called. See lines 81(prepareEntityFlushes), 92(flushEntities), 103(logFlushResults) respectively.

If you want you can go into details of each method to see exactly where the get methods called for entities.